# Render multiple charts in a PDF report without saving images

Tags: php, pdf, charts, mpdf

I have a report in which I want to render 4 charts (1 line chart, 2 bar charts, and 1 radar chart).

I create the PDF report with mpdf dynamically without saving it on server. The user can visit a link like https://example.com/report.php and he will be able to see the report, print it, and download it.

I have been searching the whole day and found some libraries like jpgraph and pChart but I have to save the charts first to be able to use them in the report.

The chart's content is dynamic and the report is generated by the users with this method, I would have to save all the images and delete them after.

I know Javascript can't be used in PDF.

Is there a way to render the chart directly without saving the images?

Comment: @KJ I get the chart's data from the database. All the work is done by PHP and MYSQL. It's just how to visualize the data as charts in the report

Comment: @KJ I create the pdf files dynamically without saving them on the server. the user can print or download the pdf. But the issue is with the charts.

Comment: So the user goes to a link like that https://example.com/report.php and he is able to see a pdf file. I'm struggling adding the charts to the pdf